# How do I draw a line using Cypress

Tags: cypress

**Using CYpress I'm trying to simulate a signature action** on one of the form I'm automating. Could someone help me understand how can I draw a line.
I'm trying below, doesn't work. Just puts a dot.

`cy.get("[data-testid='xyz']").trigger('mousedown', 'center').click({release:false}).trigger('mouseup',5,5).trigger('mouseleave');`

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a dot, you may get a line by adding a mousemove

```js
cy.get("[data-testid='xyz']")
  .trigger('mousedown', 'center')
  .trigger('mousemove',5,5)        // from center to just inside top left
  .trigger('mouseup')
```

`click({release:false})` isn't a valid option, but hopefully `mousedown` will stay down until `mouseup`,

Answer (score 0):

Find your exact coordinates, Try It:

```
cy.get("[datatestid='xyz']").trigger('mousedown','center')
.click({release:false})
.trigger('mousemove',{ clientX: 200, clientY: 300 })
.trigger('mouseup',5,5)
.trigger('mouseleave');
```

Courtesy:https://softans.com/draw-a-line-using-cypress/

Comment: You have typo "triger" wrong spelling

Comment: I tried to find co-ordinates and above commands, didn't help mouse moves without drawing .

Comment: It means mouse is not down

Answer (score 0):

it's important to include the `eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent'` param

```
const draw = () => {
  cy.get(CANVAS)
    .should('exist')
    .trigger('mousedown', {
      x: 10,
      y: 300,
      force: true,
      eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',
    })
    .trigger('mousemove', {
      x: 10,
      y: 240,
      force: true,
      eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',
    })
    .trigger('mouseup', {
      x: 10,
      y: 240,
      force: true,
      eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',
    });
};
```